# 1-5 V to 4-20 mA current loop transmitter

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, circuit-analysis, current

[image]

The above circuit take an input voltage in the range of 1-5 V and gives the corresponding current output of 4-20 mA.

I got the circuit reference from [Analog](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/D61_EN-Convert.pdf).

I understood the functioning of the first stage; the current following through R1 is Vin/R1, the same current flows through R2, therefore the voltage at the bottom of R2 is a 24 V voltage drop across R2, but it is written in the reference sheet that the voltage across R2 and R3 is equal.

I don't understand how the voltage across R2 and R3 can be equal.

Answer (score 2):

@power machines
Briefly, the voltage across R2 and R3 should be approx the same because if the operational amplifier work into the linear region the differential voltage between the negative and positive input of the opamp should be approx equal to 0. This is due to the operational amplifier theory.

Answer (score 0):

If the voltage across R3 is not equal the op-amp drives the MOSFET gate in the correct direction to increase or decrease the current through the load (assumed to be connected between R6 and ground) so that the voltages are equalized.

If the load current is too low then the voltage at (-) input will be too high (voltage across R3 is too low) and the op-amp output is driven low, which (being a P-channel MOSFET with source connected to +24) will cause the MOSFET to turn on more, and drive the voltages closer together.

The voltage across R2 is *driven* by the input voltage and resulting drain current from M2 (through the LH op-amp). The voltage across R3 is driven by the RH op-amp  to equalize the voltages, via changing the load current. Since there is no gate current to speak of, the current through R3 is about exactly equal to the load current.

If the load resistance is too high (say it is open) then the MOSFET will have -24V Vgs but no drain current to speak of, so the voltages cannot equalize.

Note that this will exceed the absolute maximum rating of most MOSFETs so maybe this design is not ideal. I don't see a datasheet for an IRF9Z245, but the IRF9Z24S (maybe a typo) is only rated for -20V absolute maximum.

Comment: i am using this circuit at 12V@SpehroPefhany

Comment: but i didn't understood how voltage at R3 is equal to R2@SpehroPefhany

Comment: If the P-channel MOSFET is rated suitably then it's okay.

Comment: Also note that with a 12V supply your maximum load will be less than 330 ohms, probably 300 ohms would be a better spec.