# Creating a 4-20mA current loop based on a voltage

Tags: current, dac

I need some help/advice on making this circuit. A DAC outputs a 0-5V or 1-5V or whatever voltage I want, and it needs to be converted into a 4-20mA signal that goes into the 4-20mA pin of a [Hawk-4G device](https://www.digitalmatter.com/devices/hawk/hawk-tech-specs/). I am not sure how this circuit would work, whether I should use an op-amp or an LT3092 or what, but the current going into the pin needs to be consistent based on the voltage I set on the DAC. For example, 1V = 4mA, 5V = 20mA, and then 2V = 8mA, and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Please link to the specific pdf data sheet for the plug-in I/O card option that describes the 4-20 mA input requirements please. There are two options it seems and the specification of the one you are using is likely to be needed.

Comment: Typically, if your input signal ranges from 0-5V, then 0V would map to 4 mA and 5 V would map to 20 mA. 0 mA is considered a fault, and 4 mA is considered the lowest valid signal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Andyaka its the agTech1 card

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522180/1-5-v-to-4-20-ma-current-loop-transmitter